# Custom extension is not passing magento 2 validation

Tags: php, magento2

We have created a simple Magento 2 extension and verified it using their tool: https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp

However, when we submit the extension for technical review, it always fails with the following error:

[Magento extension review error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tepqg.png)

I have searched all over and all I found was to make sure that we did not have the attribute **cacheable="false"** in any block that we were injecting because it would invalidate the entire full page cache. We do not have that attribute at all.

Is there anything else I should test in order to pass Magento 2 technical review?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that pages in report

Assertions: 
AssertHitHeader: validates that after sending a request for the test page, the server returns HIT for the expected header.

So
Inspect page headers- 
Success criteria:

The first time accessing the page will always be a MISS.

Subsequent times accessing the page will be a HIT.

How to verify - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html

Comment: Just to clarify, should I request the page to a test product in my store? I ask because I do not have the products/categories that are shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @NumaQuevedo do not catch you, in your screenshot I can see only urls

Comment: that is a screenshot of the results sent by magento after they run their automated tests. After investigating further, those urls correspond with test data that they have on their end. Still, validation is not passing even if I tested our extension locally and verified that product pages work.